# Have some way to put annotations under series in apex charts?

Tags: apexcharts, ng-apexcharts

I have this line chart in apex charts and have to fill some lines according to line value

To this, I've found the Annotations property in documentation, but this fill over the series and I need this color under the serie.

I have tried to use annotations property, but have not property to set the position.. if will be under or over.
[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RLpC.png)